# How can I select a nested element without an id or class?

Tags: javascript, dom

For example, suppose I had the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div></div>
```

and I wished to fin the value within the td element with an X in it.
I know that I would obviously use

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("TD")[0].innerHTML;
```

in order to select that specific td element, and not one of the others.
However, given that I know the path to the element, how can javascript be used in this way to select this particular value?

Comment: Just wondering what you're doing that you need this for? Also, I'm not sure what you're asking... I think you're trying to figure out which `<td>` has an X in it? Seems like a place for `<input type="radio">`

Comment: I'm trying to select/retrieve data values from an external source which does not use any identifiers with their elements.

Comment: You said "given that I know the path to the element," so what's the problem?

Comment: I know the path to the element, but I do not know how to use javascript to select that element. I only know how to use javascript to select an element which is not nested and can be accessed directly through a unique identifier.

Comment: For example, I expect that the code required would look something like the below, however this is obviously not correct.

document.getElementsByTagName("div", "table", "tr", "td[0]").innerHTML;

Comment: you can also use document.queryselector

Comment: Please reconsider your selected answer, as it's a very poor answer. I meant to answer sooner, but accidentally posted my answer on the wrong question, and had to delete it and then wait before posting it here.

Comment: Do you want to select the **first** `td`, or the `td` containing "X", wherever it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first get the tr

```js
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var foo = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
console.log(foo);
```

```html
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>X</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div></div>
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. It works just because the X is in the first td. It is pointless to get the tr. You don't need it.

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40444134/3421659) instead

Comment: @germanfr it works fine, no matter where the xtd is, you can put it as the second, also works

Comment: No, it doesn't work. With [0] you are always selecting the first td inside the first tr you find. It may have an X (like your example) or it may not. But you won't know where it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Just keep going.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]
```

**Option 2:** `querySelector`

```
document.querySelector("div tr td")
```

`querySelector` is just like using CSS selectors. You can even select by class or id. Note: if there are more than one elements to select, use `querySelectorAll`.

As a side note, there's an important difference between `document.querySelectorAll("div")` and `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`, in that the former returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and the latter returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Documentation: [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Why would I use Option 1 when I could use Option 2?

Comment: @torazaburo Just depends on your limitations, I think. I'm pretty sure selecting by tagname is slightly faster though. Also, again, `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList and `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection, but that's probably not important in all cases